# Google + login integration prompt

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, oauth, google-plus

I'm working on google + sign in integration for my php project. I followed the steps given in this link https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/.

Every thing works fine. But my problem is, while creating the project in google api I gave my redirect url. Upon directing to that url, I will lock the user's information unto my database coming from google+. But since the login is done through prompt, it is getting closed after logging in and not get redirected to that "redirect url" given while creating the project. Now how to do this in prompted window and refresh my current page so that user is logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are signing in using JavaScript, you no longer need to perform a redirect in the same way that you traditionally needed to in OAuth 2.0 flows so unless you are using the non JavaScript flow, the redirect URIs are not as important. The JavaScript client will return credentials when the user signs up for the first time that can be exchanged from your server to enable access as you're trying to get.

The PHP quickstart sample shows you how to perform all of the steps you need:

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php

This sample will show you how to use the PostMessage style response from the Google+ Sign-In button and will allow you to use a JavaScript redirect for getting the access credentials to your server.